# Необходимо найти неизвестный кусок кода HTML через парсер C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Код-C# записывает HTML-код в переменные типа string. В этих переменных мне необходимо найти фрагмент известный мне только от части, т.е. я знаю то с чего он начинается и заканчивается, а то что по середине мне необходимо найти.
Код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstLinkCodeByMain;
            string secondLinkCodeByMain;
            
            firstLinkCodeByMain = EnteringFirstLink();
            secondLinkCodeByMain = EnteringSecondLink();

            firstLinkCodeByMain = FindHTML(firstLinkCodeByMain);
            secondLinkCodeByMain = FindHTML(secondLinkCodeByMain);

            string firstLinkResult = Regex.Match(firstLinkCodeByMain, @"<div class=""friend_block_content"">/*тут должно быть неизвестное слово*/<br>").Groups[1].Value;
            
            if (firstLinkResult == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("К сожалению ничего не найдено");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(firstLinkResult);
        }
```

Почему этот код не может найти неизвестное слово?
Как можно найти это неизвестное слово?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Используйте нормальные парсеры, а не ReGex. HTML парсят регулярками 2 категории людей - Perl-разработчики и новички, не умеющие писать свой код. Но они не знают, что регулярки для HTML - это во-первых медленно, во-вторых сложно, в-третьих ненадежно. Используйте специально предназначенный для HTML парсер, например HtmlAgilityPack или AngleSharp.